# text enlarges the flexbox container

Tags: css, flexbox, longtext

I don't know how to do for the text not enlarges the flex container.

If I fill one box with text when the `@media` is `@media screen and (min-width:600px)` this box is bigger than 50%. And I want to keep the same percent that when the boxes are empty.

This is the codepen: http://codepen.io/elcollage_com/pen/LpoGVN?editors=110

Thanks.

The example:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-items:stretch;
    height: 100%;
}

.left {order:2; background:red; flex-basis:100%;}
.middle {order:1; background: green; flex-basis:100%;}
.right {order:3; background:yellow; flex-basis:100%;}


@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
   .container {
       flex-flow: column wrap;
   } 

    .left {
      flex: 1 0 50%;
      order: 1;
          
    }
    .middle {
      flex: 1 0 50%;
      order: 3;
        
    }
    .right {
      flex: 1 0 50%;
      order: 2;
        
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
   .container {
       flex-flow: row nowrap;
   } 

    .left {
        flex:1 0 37%;
        order:1;
    }
    .middle {
        flex:1 0 21%;
        order:2;
    }
    .right {
        flex:1 0 37%;
        order:3;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I fill one box with text when the `@media` is `@media screen and (min-width:600px)` this box is bigger than 50%. And I want to keep the same percent that when the boxes are empty.

You have `flex: 1 0 50%` applied to each flex item in the media query. However, the flex container is changed in the media query to *column-direction*. Therefore, the 50% `flex-basis` in the `flex` property refers to `height` not `width`. And when you add text to each box, the height remains at 50%, but the width increases.

Your code:

```
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
   .container {
       flex-flow: column wrap; /* flex container changed to column direction */
   } 

    .left {
      flex: 1 0 50%; /* 50% refers to height not width */
      order: 1;

    }
    .middle {
      flex: 1 0 50%;
      order: 3;

    }
    .right {
      flex: 1 0 50%;
      order: 2;    
    }
}
```

So if you want each box to be at 50% width (with or without text), you need to make some adjustments to your code.

Revised code:

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-items:stretch;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; /* new */
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
   .container {
       flex-flow: column wrap;
   } 

    .left {
      flex: 1 0 50%;
      order: 1;
      width: 50%; /* new */

    }
    .middle {
      flex: 1 0 50%;
      order: 3;
      width: 50%; /* new */

    }
    .right {
      flex: 1 0 50%;
      order: 2;    
      width: 50%; /* new */
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwooRz)

If you have text that overflows a box vertically, you can manage the excess with properties such as [**`overflow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) and [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).